# Spring Security AuthenticationManager checks only password

Tags: java, spring, authentication, jwt

I am having an issue with the way I check credentials using `AuthenticationManager`. I have the following code:

**SpringBootApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityJwtApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringSecurityJwtApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityJwtApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class HelloWorldController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/access-token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        }
        catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password", e);
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService
            .loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        final String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }

}
```

**AuthenticationRequest.java**

```
public class AuthenticationRequest implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    //need default constructor for JSON Parsing
    public AuthenticationRequest() {}

    public AuthenticationRequest(String username, String password) {

        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setPassword(password);
    }

}
```

**MyUserDetailsService.java**

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return new User("userTest", "passwordTest", new ArrayList<>());
    }

}
```

The issue I am facing with is that this line

```
authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
```

succeeds even if my username is incorrect.

For an example,

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" --data '{"username":"wrongUser","password":"passwordTest"}' localhost:8080/access-token
```

will return a 200 response, while

```
curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/json" --data '{"username":"userTest","password":"wrongPass"}' localhost:8080/access-token
```

will give back an expected 403 error.
Any idea what might be the issue?

**EDIT**

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (username != null && username.equals(CORRECTUSERNAME)) {
            return new User(username, CORRECTPASSWORD, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your `UserDetailsService` is wrong. It always returns ther user, whereas it should only return a user if the username matches, if not it should throw a `UsernameNotFoundExcepion` (as stated in the javadoc).

Comment: @M.Deinum So something like this (Edited the question)?

Comment: Something like that yes.